# URL that opens a file

Tags: malware, url

I have received a spam message most probably being malware.

The message is in **plain text format** contains a hyperlink with the exact syntax

```
http://example.com/folder/
```

When this is clicked (under Outlook), it immediately downloads a .doc file without any confirm.

How can such a link work ?

Note that I am not asking how to shield against such attacks. I am asking how technically such a link can cause a download.

Comment: The basic answer is, the website uses some kind of javascript with exploit to be able to do this. This question, however, is considered off-topic because using exploits to do this change all the time, and as such any answer is only valid for a short while.

Comment: @LPChip: understood, thanks. (I couldn't guess it was an exploit.)

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two mechanisms which do not require scripting to be enabled, though there may well be others:-

1. The link may use a plain text string, but associate it with a different URL, as here [www.microsoft.com](http://www.ubuntu.com) (private joke), and this can reference a document which according to your browser settings may down-load automatically.
2. Most web servers when presented with a folder address will look for and open a number of default files in it (eg `index.htm`), and this can be coded to forward to another page, again a document reference, which will down-load as above.

The code for page forwarding is placed in the HTML header:

```
<head>
...
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=http://Other.Url.Com/">
...
</head>
```

To be safe, you should change your browser settings to make sure that it always prompts before down-loading or running any type of file.

Comment: @Attie - You're absolutely right: silly mistake on my part, now corrected. Thanks.

Comment: We are not in case 1, there is not hidden href. The default file explanation is convincing.